# Installing dependencies in pyinstaller bundled executable

Tags: python, command-line-interface, pyinstaller

I want to implement a CLI using python with extensions. Every extension has their own dependencies. I want commands like this:

`mycli extension install extension1`
`mycli extension uninstall extension2`

Also, i will make an executable with pyinstaller. The problem is, after I bundle it using pyinstaller, it will be compiled to exe included all the dependencies. But i want the exe without any depencencies of extensions (only with required dependencies for core app) and when I install an extension, it should be installed with it's dependencies. For example:

mycli dependencies without any extensions:

- click
- requests
- aiohttp
- xmlschema

dependencies after extension1 installed:

- click
- requests
- aiohttp
- xmlschema
- **numpy**
- **pandas**
- **scikitlearn**
- **opencv**

How can I implement something like this?

Comment: You would have to bundle pip and a python executible with the rest of the pyinstaller app since neither of those things are included in executables compiled with pyinstaller.    It can be done but it isn't really practical